# Google Maps iFrame Embed Mixed Content

Tags: google-maps, ssl, iframe, mixed-content

Can't seem to find the answer to this one in my searches. Apparently, Google Maps is available via SSL, but it still loads some insecure content/assets. I'm trying to find a fix for this.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=z6wX5r5bS180.kNLgUyxHh1tc" height="550"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about:

> Loading mixed (insecure) display content
>   "http://www.gstatic.com/gmeviewer/images/no_results-000.png" on a
>   secure page

It has already been reported (yesterday, Oct 21 2015) to Google team: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/d2BBVR-aOlA

and they said it will be fixed:

> Sha MyMaps team said:
>
> It will be fixed in a few days.